# Add text to unordered list on keyup event of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Add text to unordered list on keyup event of textarea and there should't be any li when there is no text in textarea

HTML:

```
<textarea id="activityText"></textarea>
<div id="qwe">
    <ul>
        <li id="textFromTextArea"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#activityText").keyup(function () {
    $("#textFromTextArea").text($("#activityText").val());        
})
```

If there is no text in textarea then there should't be any list, can it be possible with jQuery

https://ibb.co/gjpDTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

I moved id from `li` to `ul`. I removed `li` element since you want to do not show marker.

```
<div id="qwe">
    <ul id="textFromTextArea">
    </ul>
</div>

<textarea id="ActivityText"></textarea>
```

and js:

```
$("#ActivityText").keyup(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if($("#textFromTextArea li").length===0) {
       var $li = $("<li>");
       $li.html(val);

       $("#textFromTextArea").append($li);
    } else {
       $("#textFromTextArea li").html(val);
    }
});
```

**Option 2:**

Show/hide li element, preserve actual HTML you wrote but I add a CSS class `hide`

```
<div id="qwe">
    <ul>
      <li id="textFromTextArea" class="hide"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<textarea id="ActivityText"></textarea>
```

css

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

and js

```
$("#ActivityText").keyup(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var $li = $("#textFromTextArea");

    if(val.length === 0) {
        $li.addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $li.removeClass("hide");      
    }

    $li.html(val);
});
```

Comment: YES! Thank you!

Comment: If OP wants this way, is possible too.

Comment: @SnakeEyes can u do this for me?

Comment: @SnakeEyes , Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

```
<textarea id="activityText"></textarea>
<div id="qwe">
    <ul id="list">

    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var textval = '';
$("#activityText").on("keyup", function() {
    textval = $(this).val();
    if (textval.length > 0) {
        $("#list").html('<li>' + textval + '</li>');
    } else {
        $("#list").empty();
    }
});
```